# Relation between engine size and its power to weight ratio

Tags: mechanical-engineering, energy-efficiency, engines

Is there a relation between engine size and its power to weight ratio? For example if you shrink the engine to half the size will it have exactly half the power?

Answer (score 2):

No, more like 1/8. Power (and weight) is most closely related to volume, which changes with the cube of the linear dimensions.

Comment: so how will the power change after reducing volume by half?

Answer (score 2):

as you shrink a heat engine, its volume (in which power is developed) falls faster than its surface area (through which losses occur) which means a small engine will inherently be lossier than a large engine of the same design. This scaling relationship is universal, which means that engine designers prefer one large engine instead of two smaller ones.